# What are phantomChildren in package.json?

Tags: npm, package, yarnpkg, package.json

When I install a module, a list of `phantomChildren` appears in the `package.json` file. What are `phantomChildren`?

Comment: Still actual. It is kind of metadata, but it adds additional dependencies and packages which are not required

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I didn't find official documentation for `npm` package `phantomChildren`. But encountered some other explanation: https://rushjs.io/pages/advanced/phantom_deps/. It is about `rast`, but explains behavior of `npm` dependencies pretty well.

For example library `A` might import definitions from libraries `B` and `C`, but then `B` and `C` can both import from `D`, which creates a “diamond dependency” between these four packages.

> A *“phantom dependency”* occurs when a project uses a package that is
>   not defined in its `package.json` file.

Some live example:

```
my-library/package.json

{
  "name": "my-library",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "minimatch": "^3.0.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2"
  }
}

my-library/lib/index.js

var minimatch = require("minimatch")
var expand = require("brace-expansion");  // ???
var glob = require("glob")  // ???
```

> Wait a sec – two of these libraries are not declared as dependencies
>   in the package.json file. How is this working at all!? It turns out
>   that brace-expansion is a dependency of minimatch, and glob is a
>   dependency of rimraf. During installation, NPM has flattened their
>   folders to be under my-library/node_modules. The NodeJS require()
>   function finds them there because it probes for folders without
>   considering the package.json files at all.

**To summarize:** if package uses dependencies of it's own dependencies, it can be treated as phantomChildren. Package doesn't have such dependencies directly but uses it from other places.

Comment: It's pretty astounding that in 2022 this is still essentially still one of the only threads on the internet talking about this

Comment: But why would someone import a module not listed in his package.json in the first place ?!

Comment: @Qiulang Might be plenty reasons but most common one I've seen is when a dependency uses some utility library like lodash and then a new developer joins a project, imports lodash automatically (because he's been using it for years) and it works thanks to lodash being a phantom dependency.